# How will i post tweet update to all users who allow my twitter app?

Tags: twitter

I already stored oauth_tokens of all users on my database and other user info.

I only wonder on how will I post tweet update on their profiles?

Any idea guys? Please help.

Comment: We don't know, how will you? This isn't a very specific question. What programming language? What are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to solve the technical question read Twitter's guidelines for API developers. Tweeting into the account of everyone who authorizes your account without their *explicit* and informed permission will get you banned from Twitter real fast. Ask them if they want to have you tweet something before doing it.